# Notification with inverted color with dark mode

Tags: notifications, android-10, dark-mode

On Android 10, negative images i.e images with inverted color are displayed in the notification from custom-notification apps when dark mode is enabled.

Notification with light theme/dark theme:

[image] [image]

How to prevent that from happening?

Comment: The image is not [simply inverted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeLPJ.png) since the inversion of blue<->orange. Instead, these are actually 2 different images specially designed by Amazon themself; one for light theme, another for dark theme. Perhaps the follow-up/real question is: "*How to force an app using light theme's images on dark mode's notification?*"

Comment: No, they aren't, Actually, I have only captured the screenshot of these notifications on my device. and they are same notification, the only difference is of theme .

Comment: It's possible for an app to detect if the Android system is on light/dark mode, then the app can customize the notification (or, everything) that depends on it, including the image on the notification. Also, considering that common ad/promotion images might have already been downloaded and cached already, so it can be swapped immediately. That said, we need more data points if this is only from this specific notification, or only from the Amazon app, or all images, and also it might be helpful to know the device model unless you know if this is a global issue on Android 10.

Comment: Firstly, this notification is not from amazon app, and this is happening only for custom notifications(layout designed with remote view) only if I use android-defined templet the notification image doesn't change color.

Comment: After a quick research, I noticed [it also happened on the Facebook app and the New York Times app](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/d5ilu5/is_android_10_dark_theme_notification_bar_just_a/). I stand corrected. However, whether it's a bug or not, I'm not sure if there's a way for the end-user to fix this (perhaps need rooting? Magisk/EdXposed module?). For developer-approach solutions, you have to rely on Stack Overflow's community instead.